# Installation of Google Cloud SDK for Windows fails

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

Whenever I try to run the Google Cloud SDK Installer it gives me the following error:
**Unzip failed: Error opening ZIP file.**

I've given the output folder as:
C:\Users\Username\Desktop\GoogleCloudSDK

Can somebody tell me why this is happening.

Comment: Best option for such issues is to file a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559662.

Comment: Which version did you download per https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned? Looks the issue should be caused by your unzip tool instead of the file.

Comment: What is the operating system where you are trying to install? Could you try to install on a different machine for comparison reasons? Installation file may have corrupted while downloading the executable. I would recommend to download again from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads). Also make sure that an antivirus is not blocking access to the file.

Comment: hi @Faizan this issue has been resolved. I'm not facing this issue anymore. However, the issue was prevalent a few months ago and the link provided in the google docs was not working. But somehow it automatically worked a few days later back then following the same steps mentioned in the docs. But thank you anyways :)

P.S. I was using Windows OS